# Conversion of int values to numerals in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I would like to know if there is a built-in way to convert integer values into numerals in PostgreSQL?

As an example, is it possible to convert the integer `10` into the string `TEN`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in. For this sort of thing your best bet will be to make use of PostgreSQL's pluggable procedural languages. Use PL/Perl or PL/Python with a suitable Perl or Python library to do the job.

In this case I'd probably use PL/Perl with [`Lingua::EN::Numbers`](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Lingua-EN-Numbers-1.01/lib/Lingua/EN/Numbers.pm).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION num2en(numeric) RETURNS text AS $$
use Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en);
return num2en($_[0]);
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

You'll need to install `Lingua::EN::Numbers` into the Perl being used by PostgreSQL using CPAN or system packages first. In my case (Fedora 19) this was a simple `yum install perl-Lingua-EN-Numbers.noarch`, then I could:

```
regress=> SELECT num2en(10);
 num2en 
--------
 ten
(1 row)

regress=# SELECT num2en(NUMERIC '142.5');
                num2en                
--------------------------------------
 one hundred and forty-two point five
(1 row)
```

By default the function is accessible by normal users so you don't have to issue any extra `GRANT`s.

Comment: +1 good one. I think it's not very hard to write one (I think i did that when solved some of projecteuler.net problems), but it's always nice to have tested function

Comment: @RomanPekar Agreed. One could easily use the code in `Lingua::EN::Numbers` as a model for a pure SQL (or PL/PgSQL at least) implementation.  http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/NEILB/Lingua-EN-Numbers-1.04/lib/Lingua/EN/Numbers.pm . Greatly simplified if you don't need the fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT split_part (cash_words (10::VARCHAR::MONEY), 'dollar', 1);
```

It's a internal function of PostgreSQL.